# openai npm package giving error on deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Im receiving this error in my backend when I go to deploy. I have never gotten this error only since I installed the openai package in the backend.

My node version is 20 so node:fs should work just fine. It also should be found because it's built into node. I don't import it anywhere, so I'm guessing the open ai package uses it or depends on it.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
Require stack:
- /srv/node_modules/openai/_shims/node-runtime.js
- /srv/node_modules/openai/_shims/auto/runtime-node.js
- /srv/node_modules/openai/_shims/index.js
- /srv/node_modules/openai/streaming.js
- /srv/node_modules/openai/core.js
- /srv/node_modules/openai/index.js
- /srv/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/openai/_shims/node-runtime.js:37:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/srv/node_modules/openai/_shims/node-runtime.js',
    '/srv/node_modules/openai/_shims/auto/runtime-node.js',
    '/srv/node_modules/openai/_shims/index.js',
    '/srv/node_modules/openai/streaming.js',
    '/srv/node_modules/openai/core.js',
    '/srv/node_modules/openai/index.js',
    '/srv/index.js'
  ]
}
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 7.7.6 -> 10.5.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.0` to update!
npm notice
```

Comment: What command(s) are you running to produce this output?

Comment: “*My node version is 20 so node:fs should work just fine*” Are you absolutely positive you’re running this with Node 20? The version of `npm` you’re running is over 3 years old, which would tip me off that you’re also potentially running a more outdated version of Node.

Comment: I'm using a makefile and running "make prod-build" and then "make prod-deploy".

And yes my node version is 20.5.1 I do node -v in that is what is the output.